# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS keeps hanging but songs keep playing background

Tags: freeze

Ubuntu 22.04 LTS keeps hanging for some reason. can someone please suggest a way out?
log file is attached.

Log file:

```
16:55:26 kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0c1a tx timeout
16:55:24 kernel: PM: suspend exit
16:55:24 kernel: video LNXVIDEO:01: Restoring backlight state
16:55:24 kernel: Restarting tasks ... done.
16:55:24 kernel: OOM killer enabled.
16:55:24 kernel: 
16:55:24 kernel: R13: 00000000000000fa R14: 00000000000000f9 R15: 0000000000000200
16:55:24 kernel: R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000286 R12: 0000000000000001
16:55:24 kernel: RBP: 00007f9814a7ed48 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
16:55:24 kernel: RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000080 RDI: 000000c00003c848
16:55:24 kernel: RAX: fffffffffffffe00 RBX: 000000c00003c700 RCX: 000000000045da83
16:55:24 kernel: RSP: 002b:00007f9814a7ed00 EFLAGS: 00000286 ORIG_RAX: 00000000000000ca
16:55:24 kernel: RIP: 0033:0x45da83
16:55:24 kernel:  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x61/0xcb
16:55:24 kernel: Call Trace:
16:55:24 kernel: task:canonical-livep state:D stack:    0 pid: 5007 ppid:  3328 flags:0x00004226
16:55:24 kernel:  </TASK>
16:55:24 kernel: R13: 0000000000000000 R14: 00007fd87403fc18 R15: 00007fd87403fc28
16:55:24 kernel: R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000293 R12: 0000000000000000
16:55:24 kernel: RBP: 00007fd87403fda0 R08: 00007fd87403fc18 R09: 000000000000000c
16:55:24 kernel: RDX: 0000000000000011 RSI: 00007fd87403fc28 RDI: 0000000000000018
16:55:24 kernel: RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 00007fd87403fdf8 RCX: 00007fd879ec7c16
16:55:24 kernel: RSP: 002b:00007fd87403fbd0 EFLAGS: 00000293 ORIG_RAX: 000000000000002c
16:55:24 kernel: RIP: 0033:0x7fd879ec7c16
16:55:24 kernel:  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x61/0xcb
16:55:24 kernel: Call Trace:
16:55:24 kernel: task:ThreadPoolForeg state:D stack:    0 pid: 4684 ppid:  4671 flags:0x00000006
16:55:24 kernel:  </TASK>
16:55:24 kernel: R13: 0000000000000009 R14: 0000563f31c49d20 R15: 0000563f313481d0
16:55:24 kernel: R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 0000563f313ac160
16:55:24 kernel: RBP: 00000000c00464af R08: 00007f86b8ca8b40 R09: 0000563f32c00610
16:55:24 kernel: RDX: 00007ffe8e48ad4c RSI: 00000000c00464af RDI: 0000000000000009
16:55:24 kernel: RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 00007ffe8e48ad4c RCX: 00007f86d2753aff
16:55:24 kernel: RSP: 002b:00007ffe8e48acb0 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000010
16:55:24 kernel: RIP: 0033:0x7f86d2753aff
16:55:24 kernel:  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x61/0xcb
16:55:24 kernel: Call Trace:
16:55:24 kernel: task:gnome-shell     state:D stack:    0 pid: 1643 ppid:  1463 flags:0x00000006
16:55:24 kernel:  </TASK>
16:55:24 kernel: R13: 00007ffcbc7f5f50 R14: 00007ffcbc7f5f4c R15: 0000000000000000
16:55:24 kernel: R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000293 R12: 0000000000000000
16:55:24 kernel: RBP: 0000564963ed1040 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
16:55:24 kernel: RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 00007ffcbc7f5e00 RDI: 000000000000000c
16:55:24 kernel: RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000000000000056 RCX: 00007fa0d94c2b4d
16:55:24 kernel: RSP: 002b:00007ffcbc7f5dc0 EFLAGS: 00000293 ORIG_RAX: 000000000000002e
16:55:24 kernel: RIP: 0033:0x7fa0d94c2b4d
16:55:24 kernel:  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x61/0xcb
16:55:24 kernel: Call Trace:
16:55:24 kernel: task:NetworkManager  state:D stack:    0 pid:  745 ppid:     1 flags:0x00000006
16:55:24 kernel: Freezing of tasks failed after 20.001 seconds (4 tasks refusing to freeze, wq_busy=0):
16:55:24 kernel: 
16:55:24 kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0c1a tx timeout
16:55:24 kernel: Freezing user space processes ... 
16:55:24 kernel: Filesystems sync: 0.085 seconds
16:55:04 kernel: PM: suspend entry (s2idle)
16:55:04 kernel: video LNXVIDEO:01: Restoring backlight state
16:55:04 kernel: Restarting tasks ... done.
16:55:04 kernel: OOM killer enabled.
16:55:04 kernel: 
16:55:04 kernel: R13: 00000000000000fa R14: 00000000000000f9 R15: 0000000000000200
16:55:04 kernel: R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000286 R12: 0000000000000001
16:55:04 kernel: RBP: 00007f9814a7ed48 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
16:55:04 kernel: RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000080 RDI: 000000c00003c848
16:55:04 kernel: RAX: fffffffffffffe00 RBX: 000000c00003c700 RCX: 000000000045da83
16:55:04 kernel: RSP: 002b:00007f9814a7ed00 EFLAGS: 00000286 ORIG_RAX: 00000000000000ca
16:55:04 kernel: RIP: 0033:0x45da83
16:55:04 kernel:  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x61/0xcb
16:55:04 kernel: Call Trace:
16:55:04 kernel: task:canonical-livep state:D stack:    0 pid: 5007 ppid:  3328 flags:0x00004226
16:55:04 kernel:  </TASK>
16:55:04 kernel: R13: 0000000000000009 R14: 0000563f31c49d20 R15: 0000563f313481d0
16:55:04 kernel: R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 0000563f313ac160
16:55:04 kernel: RBP: 00000000c00464af R08: 00007f86b8ca8b40 R09: 0000563f32c00610
16:55:04 kernel: RDX: 00007ffe8e48ad4c RSI: 00000000c00464af RDI: 0000000000000009
16:55:04 kernel: RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 00007ffe8e48ad4c RCX: 00007f86d2753aff
16:55:04 kernel: RSP: 002b:00007ffe8e48acb0 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000010
16:55:04 kernel: RIP: 0033:0x7f86d2753aff
16:55:04 kernel:  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x61/0xcb
16:55:04 kernel: Call Trace:
16:55:04 kernel: task:gnome-shell     state:D stack:    0 pid: 1643 ppid:  1463 flags:0x00000006
16:55:04 kernel:  </TASK>
16:55:04 kernel: R13: 00007ffcbc7f5f50 R14: 00007ffcbc7f5f4c R15: 0000000000000000
16:55:04 kernel: R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000293 R12: 0000000000000000
16:55:04 kernel: RBP: 0000564963ed1040 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
16:55:04 kernel: RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 00007ffcbc7f5e00 RDI: 000000000000000c
16:55:04 kernel: RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000000000000056 RCX: 00007fa0d94c2b4d
16:55:04 kernel: RSP: 002b:00007ffcbc7f5dc0 EFLAGS: 00000293 ORIG_RAX: 000000000000002e
16:55:04 kernel: RIP: 0033:0x7fa0d94c2b4d
16:55:04 kernel:  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x61/0xcb
16:55:04 kernel: Call Trace:
16:55:04 kernel: task:NetworkManager  state:D stack:    0 pid:  745 ppid:     1 flags:0x00000006
16:55:04 kernel: Freezing of tasks failed after 20.008 seconds (3 tasks refusing to freeze, wq_busy=0):
16:54:44 kernel: Filesystems sync: 0.063 seconds
16:54:44 kernel: PM: suspend entry (deep)
16:52:51 kernel: usb 2-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 4
16:44:24 kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
16:44:24 kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
16:44:24 kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
16:44:24 kernel: scsi host6: usb-storage 2-1.1:1.0
16:44:24 kernel: usb-storage 2-1.1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
16:44:24 kernel: usb 2-1.1: SerialNumber: 4C530001140224108102
```

Comment: computers specs? RAM size?

Comment: I could be wrong but it looks like it is trying to hibernate or sleep (`PM: suspend entry (deep)`) but it is [failing to freeze some tasks](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1346908/suspend-freezing-of-tasks-failed-after-20-seconds).